# How to pull the average sales per visit of the top 10% of customers from 3 segments in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm newer to my job and i am not used to doing queries as complicated as the one i am being asked to do. Please help! I'm trying to pull the average sales per visit of the top 10% of customers from 3 customer segments. I'm stuck on pulling only the top 10% of customers. Here are two sample tables and what i have so far.

```
SELECT 
    cust_segment.segment, 
    AVG(cust_sales.sales) / cust_sales.visits AS "sales/vist"
FROM 
    cust_segment 
INNER JOIN 
    cust_sales ON cust_segment.Customer = cust_sales.Customer
WHERE 
    cust_sales in (SELECT TOP 10 Percent cust_sales.sales, cust_segement.segment
                   FROM cust_segment 
                   INNER JOIN cust_sales ON cust_segment.customer = cust_sales.customer)
GROUP BY 
    segment;
```

cust_segment

```
+-------------+---------+
|  Customer   | Segment |
+-------------+---------+ 
| 10000834678 | A       |
| 10000467169 | A       |
| 10000217202 | B       |
| 10001562687 | C       |
| 10000742574 | C       |
| 10001577918 | A       |
| 10000825179 | B       |
| 10000019009 | B       |
| 10001225606 | C       |
| 10000473429 | A       |
+-------------+---------+
```

cust_sales

```
+-------------+----------------+--------+
|  Customer   |     Sales      | Visits |
+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 10000834678 |  $    54.56    |      8 |
| 10000467169 |  $    27.61    |      7 |
| 10000217202 |  $  150.01     |     39 |
| 10001562687 |  $    39.59    |      8 |
| 10000742574 |  $    18.35    |      9 |
| 10001577918 |  $    23.72    |      4 |
| 10000825179 |  $       7.69  |      7 |
| 10000019009 |  $    94.41    |     47 |
| 10001225606 |  $    36.00    |     12 |
| 10000473429 |  $       5.76  |      6 |
+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

It should return:

```
+---------+-------------+
| Segment | Sales/Visit |
+---------+-------------+
| A       | 6.82        |
| B       | 3.846410256 |
| C       | 4.94875     |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Could you add more snippet to show your table structure, that would give enough info about your db and your sql statements. I believe from there we can come up with an appropriate query for your problem

Comment: Based on the data you provided, how do you get the 6.82 for Segment A? In other words, is it top 10 percent Sales, top 10 percent Visits, or top 10 percent in Sales/Visit? Is top 10 percent based on each segment or every customer?

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause, you have a `cust_sales IN (....)` , but then in the subquery inside the brackets, you select **two** columns from the table - that won't work. You need to select **only ONE** column - that one that corresponds to the `cust_sales` that you're checking against this sub-expression.

Comment: what do you mean by top 10% customer ?how do you define it ?

Comment: @BenkowalskiHi is that answer satisfied your requirement

Comment: Yes, thank you both answers worked for my data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
    seg.Segment,
    SUM( sales.Sales ) / SUM( sales.Visits ) AS [Sales/Visit]

FROM 
    cust_segment AS seg

    LEFT OUTER JOIN cust_sales AS sales
        ON seg.Customer = sales.Customer
        AND seg.Customer IN (
            SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT sa.Customer 
            FROM cust_sales AS sa
                INNER JOIN cust_segment AS sg
                    ON sg.Segment = seg.Segment
                    AND sg.Customer = sa.Customer
            ORDER BY sa.Sales DESC
        )

GROUP BY 
    seg.Segment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cust_segment( Customer   , Segment )
AS
(

SELECT  10000834678 , 'A' union all       
SELECT  10000467169 , 'A' union all       
SELECT  10000217202 , 'B' union all       
SELECT  10001562687 , 'C' union all       
SELECT  10000742574 , 'C' union all       
SELECT  10001577918 , 'A' union all       
SELECT  10000825179 , 'B' union all       
SELECT  10000019009 , 'B' union all       
SELECT  10001225606 , 'C' union all       
SELECT  10000473429 , 'A' 
)
,cust_sales(Customer,Sales,Visits)
AS
(
SELECT 10000834678 ,    54.56    ,      8  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000467169 ,    27.61    ,      7  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000217202 ,  150.01     ,     39  UNION ALL
SELECT 10001562687 ,    39.59    ,      8  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000742574 ,    18.35    ,      9  UNION ALL
SELECT 10001577918 ,    23.72    ,      4  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000825179 ,       7.69  ,      7  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000019009 ,    94.41    ,     47  UNION ALL
SELECT 10001225606 ,    36.00    ,     12  UNION ALL
SELECT 10000473429 ,       5.76  ,      6  
)
SELECT Segment,seg AS [Sales/Visit] FROM 
(
    SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION by seg ORDER BY Segment )Seq FROM
    (
        SELECT * ,MAX([Sales/Visit])OVER (PARTITION BY Segment  ORDER BY Segment)seg FROM
        (
        SELECT C.Customer,c.Segment,SUM(Sales) /SUM(Visits) AS [Sales/Visit] FROM cust_sales s
            INNER JOIN cust_segment c ON c.Customer=s.Customer
        GROUP BY  C.Customer,c.Segment
        )dt
    )dt2
)Final WHERE Final.Seq=1 ORDER BY 1
```

OutPut

```
Segment|Sales/Visit
------------------
  A     6.820000
  B     3.846410
  C     4.948750
```